# Trying to find display: contents alternative that I can use with my CSS grid

Tags: css, grid, display, substitution

I have a `grid` that uses `display: contents`. Unfortunately, this declaration still isn't widely supported. I'm trying to substitute it with something that's more widely supported and that wouldn't break my current `grid` design. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```css
.grid-row {
    display: contents;
}

.grid-row:hover > div {
    background-color: #262626;
    color: #fff;
}

    .grid-cell {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #808080;
        padding: .5rem;
        min-height: 4rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .grid {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 1px;
        background-color: #808080 !important;
        border: 1px solid #808080 !important;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-template-columns: auto min-content min-content;
        white-space: pre-wrap !important;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
    <div class="grid-cell">Price</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">Quantity</div>
    
    <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="grid-cell">Item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">10.00</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="grid-cell">Item 2</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">20.00</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">2</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="grid-cell">Item 3</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">30.00</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert it into table:

```css
.grid-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.grid-row:hover > div {
    background-color: #262626;
    color: #fff;
}

    .grid-cell {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #808080;
        padding: .5rem;
        line-height: 4rem;
        display: table-cell;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .grid {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        background-color: #808080 !important;
        white-space: pre-wrap !important;
        border-spacing: 1px;
    }
    
.grid > :first-of-type
{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
    <div class="grid-cell">Price</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">Quantity</div>
    
    <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="grid-cell">Item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">10.00</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="grid-cell">Item 2</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">20.00</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">2</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="grid-cell">Item 3</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">30.00</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```